# Convert byte[] to String

Tags: java, binary, arrays

Is there an easy way to print `byte[]` array ( zeros and ones, basically to every bit convert in ascii '1' or ascii '0') to the console ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. Could you give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: do you need this for debugging purposes only?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer If I understand it correctly, OP wants something like `Integer.toBinaryString()` for bytes. Baffles me why there's no such method in the `Byte` class, to be honest.

Comment: @biziclop - ah, well I read the question in a different way - that his byte array contains only zeros and ones. @Damir - please clarify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can output the individual bytes by converting their numeric value to base 2. Here are two ways to do it. In both, I will use this byte array:

```
byte[] array = "HälLø123§$%".getBytes();
```

### Walk the array

```
for(final byte b : array){
    System.out.print(Integer.toString(b & 0xFF /* thx Jason Day */, 2));
}
```

**Output:**

> 10010001100001110100100110110010011001100001110111000110001011001001100110110000101010011110010001001010

**Reference:**

- [`Integer.toString(i, radix)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

### Use BigInteger

If you want to output the entire array in one piece, use [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
System.out.println(new BigInteger(array).toString(2));
```

**Output:**

> 100100011000011101001000110110001001100110000111011100000110001001100100011001111000010101001110010010000100101

**Reference:**

- [`BigInteger(byte[])`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29)
- [`BigInteger.toString(radix)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

Comment: Careful, neither of these methods take sign extension into account.  For example, Integer.toString((byte) 130, 2) results in -1111110, not 10000010.  You need to mask off the sign bit first.

Comment: @Jason that's true for the first version (and I adjusted it, thanks) but not for the second.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) [`BinaryCodec`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/BinaryCodec.html):

```
BinaryCodec.toAsciiString(array)
```

For better control on the output, you can use `toAsciiChars(..)` and print the `char[]`.

(If you simply want to output the array values - `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`);

Comment: That would display the bytes in decimal though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @biziclop - no, nothing decimal. it will print the contents of the byte array.

Comment: Although it wasn't from me, I guess because you failed to answer the question. Which was, how to print the array in binary, not decimal.

Comment: @biziclop aha, I added an additional option for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print the binary representation of each element, you can do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("[");
String comma = "";
for (byte b : array) {
    int i = b & 0xFF; // cast to int and mask the sign bit
    sb.append(comma);
    comma = ",";
    sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
}
sb.append("]");

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This outputs individual bytes, not individual bits. But as it may still be useful for someone, I'll let it here.

---

Here the solution for my understanding of the question:

```
byte[] data = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length);
for(byte b : data) {
    sb.append(b);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

This should output `010110`.